# Issues performing integration tests on ember.js app using js-test-driver

Tags: ember.js, continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing, js-test-driver

I'm trying to integrate a small ember.js app into an existing web site. The code works just fine, but I'm having trouble getting my integration testing to work.

messaging.js

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('index', {path: '/'}, function () {
        this.resource('detail', {path: ':message_id'});
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.MessageSummary.find();
    },

    events: {
        select: function (summary) {
            this.transitionTo('detail', App.Message.find(summary.get('id')));
        }
    }
});

App.MessageSummary = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('string'),
    status: DS.attr('string'),
    by: DS.attr('string'),
    subject: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('string'),
    subject: DS.attr('string')
});

App.MessageSummary.FIXTURES = [
    {id: '1', date: '04/19/2013 8:15 PM', status: 'read', by: 'your doctor', subject: 'Your heart attack'},
    {id: '2', date: '04/19/2013 8:15 PM', status: 'read', by: 'your doctor', subject: 'Your heart attack'},
    {id: '3', date: '04/19/2013 8:15 PM', status: 'read', by: 'your doctor', subject: 'Your heart attack'},
    {id: '4', date: '04/19/2013 8:15 PM', status: 'read', by: 'your doctor', subject: 'Your heart attack'},
    {id: '5', date: '04/19/2013 8:15 PM', status: 'read', by: 'your doctor', subject: 'Your heart attack'}
];

App.Message.FIXTURES = [
    {id: '1', subject: 'Your heart attack (Detail 1)'},
    {id: '2', subject: 'Your heart attack (Detail 2)'},
    {id: '3', subject: 'Your heart attack (Detail 3)'},
    {id: '4', subject: 'Your heart attack (Detail 4)'},
    {id: '5', subject: 'Your heart attack (Detail 5)'}
];
```

messaging.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ember-data-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/messaging.js"></script>

    <title>Messaging</title>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <div>
        <table class="rounded-corner summary">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">From</th>
                <th scope="col">Subject</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {{#each model}}
            <tr {{action select this}}>
                <td>{{date}}</td>
                <td>{{status}}</td>
                <td>{{by}}</td>
                <td>{{subject}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="detail">
    <div>
        {{id}}: {{subject}}
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it's pretty trivial. Works like a charm in the browser. Given Ember is a highly opinionated, convention-over-configuration framework, integration testing seems to be the right way to go. So in trying to use our existing tooling, my jsTestDriver unit test looks like this:

jsTestDriver.conf:

```
server: http://localhost:9876

load:
- src/main/webapp/js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
- src/main/webapp/js/lib/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js
- src/main/webapp/js/lib/ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js
- src/main/webapp/js/lib/ember-data-latest.min.js

- src/test/webapp/js/emberTesting.js

- src/main/webapp/js/messaging.js

- src/test/webapp/js/jshamcrest-0.6.7.min.js
- src/test/webapp/js/jsmockito-1.0.4-minified.js

test:
- src/test/webapp/js/messagingTests.js
```

messagingTests.js

```
JsHamcrest.Integration.JsTestDriver();
JsMockito.Integration.JsTestDriver();

App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'none'
});

jQuery.fx.off = true;

TestCase('secure messaging integration tests', {
    setUp: function () {

        /*:DOC +=


         <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
         <div>
         <table class="rounded-corner summary">
         <thead>
         <tr>
         <th scope="col">Date</th>
         <th scope="col">Status</th>
         <th scope="col">From</th>
         <th scope="col">Subject</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         {{#each model}}
         <tr {{action select this}}>
         <td>{{date}}</td>
         <td>{{status}}</td>
         <td>{{by}}</td>
         <td>{{subject}}</td>
         </tr>
         {{/each}}
         </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <div>
         {{outlet}}
         </div>
         </script>

         <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="detail">
         <div>
         {{id}}: {{subject}}
         </div>
         </script>
         */
        Ember.run(function () {
            if (App.store) App.store.destroy();
            App.store = App.Store.create();
        });
        App.reset();
    },

    'test initial load loads table body': function () {
        console.log($('body').html());//debug 
        assertThat($('.summary tbody tr').length, equalTo(5));
    }
});
```

During test execution, ember.js throws an exception:

broswer console output:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:349DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:349DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:349DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.8.3
ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:349DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:18334Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
```

And the top of the stack at the time the error is thrown is:

```
checkRemoved(18334)
html(18304)
empty(19077)
empty(16899)
arrayWillChange(17700)
sendEvent(2432)
arrayContentWillChange(8909)
arrangedContentArrayWillChange(11578)
sendEvent(2432)
arrayContentWillChange(8909)
replace(12007)
insertAt(9411)
pushObject(9464)
addObject(9619)
```

and the body of the rendered html is:

```
     <div id="ember407" class="ember-view">
     <div>
     <table class="rounded-corner summary">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th scope="col">Date</th>
     <th scope="col">Status</th>
     <th scope="col">From</th>
     <th scope="col">Subject</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
     <div>
     <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
     </div>
     </div>
```

I realize I may need to use jsTestDriver's AsyncTestCase given the way ember.js's bindings works, but since ember throws an exception during rendering, I need to solve that problem first.

Ideas?